# Loading the contacts to the UITableView in a alphabetical and grouped format

Tags: android, ios, objective-c, uitableview

Customize the appearance of table view cells.

Loading the contacts to the UITableView in a alphabetical grouped format

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    Contacts *contact = [[self.contactsSections valueForKey:[[[self.contactsSections allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.backgroundView =  [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[ [UIImage imageNamed:@"contacts_bar.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:5.0]];

    // setting the Label
    UILabel *textLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(winSize.width/4.57, 0, winSize.width/1.6, cell.frame.size.height)];
    [textLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    textLabel.text = contact.firstname;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:textLabel];

    // creating the contact imageView
    UIImageView *contctImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, winSize.width/4.9, winSize.width/4.9)];
    contctImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"contact_pic.png"];
    contctImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:contctImageView];

    return cell;
}
```

i need the UI design each cell of Tableview.Image and contact name as in android contact design.Can any one help me out the issue in above code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to add imageView and label to UITableViewCell, just use the ones that the cell has:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }

        Contacts *contact = [[self.contactsSections valueForKey:[[[self.contactsSections allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.backgroundView =  [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"contacts_bar.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:5.0]];

        // setting the Label
        cell.textLabel.text = contact.firstname;

        // creating the contact imageView
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"contact_pic.png"];

        return cell;
    }
```

If you are looking for how to implement a custom cell so see this:

http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/